# Expansion of Nested Macros with reinterpret cast in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

I stumbled across the below code and really found it complex to understand the nested macro and type casting in it.

Also when i tried to compile the code , i have encountered an error

Would need an explanantion of the below code.

why BEGIN_STATE_MAP and END_STATE_MAP set as labels in Motor.h , This is really new to me

Thanks in advance

Motor.h

```
// the Motor state machine class
class Motor : public StateMachine
{
public:
    Motor() : StateMachine(ST_MAX_STATES) {}

    // external events taken by this state machine
    void Halt();
    void SetSpeed(MotorData*);
private:
    // state machine state functions
    void ST_Idle();
    void ST_Stop();
    void ST_Start(MotorData*);
    void ST_ChangeSpeed(MotorData*);

    // state map to define state function order
    BEGIN_STATE_MAP
        STATE_MAP_ENTRY(ST_Idle)
        STATE_MAP_ENTRY(ST_Stop)
        STATE_MAP_ENTRY(ST_Start)
        STATE_MAP_ENTRY(ST_ChangeSpeed)
    END_STATE_MAP

    // state enumeration order must match the order of state
    // method entries in the state map
    enum E_States {
        ST_IDLE = 0,
        ST_STOP,
        ST_START,
        ST_CHANGE_SPEED,
        ST_MAX_STATES
    };
};
#endif //MOTOR_H
```

what are BEGIN_STATE_MAP and END_STATE_MAP, This definition i found i really new,
BEGIN_STATE_MAP and END_STATE_MAP are the Macros defined in the below header file.

StateMachine.h

```
#ifndef STATE_MACHINE_H
#define STATE_MACHINE_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include "EventData.h"

struct StateStruct;

// base class for state machines
class StateMachine
{
public:
    StateMachine(int maxStates);
    virtual ~StateMachine() {}
protected:
    enum { EVENT_IGNORED = 0xFE, CANNOT_HAPPEN };
    unsigned char currentState;
    void ExternalEvent(unsigned char, EventData* = NULL);
    void InternalEvent(unsigned char, EventData* = NULL);
    virtual const StateStruct* GetStateMap() = 0;
private:
    const int _maxStates;
    bool _eventGenerated;
    EventData* _pEventData;
    void StateEngine(void);
};

typedef void (StateMachine::*StateFunc)(EventData *);
struct StateStruct
{
    StateFunc pStateFunc;
};

#define BEGIN_STATE_MAP \
public:\
const StateStruct* GetStateMap() {\
    static const StateStruct StateMap[] = {

#define STATE_MAP_ENTRY(entry)\
    { reinterpret_cast<StateFunc>(entry) },

#define END_STATE_MAP \
    { reinterpret_cast<StateFunc>(NULL) }\
    }; \
    return &StateMap[0]; }

#define BEGIN_TRANSITION_MAP \
    static const unsigned char TRANSITIONS[] = {\

#define TRANSITION_MAP_ENTRY(entry)\
    entry,

#define END_TRANSITION_MAP(data) \
    0 };\
    ExternalEvent(TRANSITIONS[currentState], data);

#endif
```

EventData.h

```
#ifndef EVENT_DATA_H
#define EVENT_DATA_H

class EventData
{
public:
   virtual ~EventData() {};
};
#endif //EVENT_DATA_H
```

While i tried to compile the code above.Below is the error that was encountered

Error

```
-------------- Build: Debug in StateMachine (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -pedantic -Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant -std=c++0x -Wextra -Wall  -c C:\Users\xprk569\StateMachine\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
In file included from C:\Users\xprk569\StateMachine\main.cpp:2:0:
C:\Users\xprk569\StateMachine\Motor.h: In member function 'virtual const StateStruct* Motor::GetStateMap()':
C:\Users\xprk569\StateMachine\StateMachine.h:40:40: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?)
     { reinterpret_cast<StateFunc>(entry) },
                                        ^
C:\Users\xprk569\StateMachine\Motor.h:29:9: note: in expansion of macro 'STATE_MAP_ENTRY'
         STATE_MAP_ENTRY(ST_Idle)
         ^
C:\Users\xprk569\StateMachine\StateMachine.h:40:40: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?)
     { reinterpret_cast<StateFunc>(entry) },
                                        ^
C:\Users\xprk569\StateMachine\Motor.h:30:9: note: in expansion of macro 'STATE_MAP_ENTRY'
         STATE_MAP_ENTRY(ST_Stop)
         ^
C:\Users\xprk569\StateMachine\StateMachine.h:40:40: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?)
     { reinterpret_cast<StateFunc>(entry) },
                                        ^
C:\Users\xprk569\StateMachine\Motor.h:31:9: note: in expansion of macro 'STATE_MAP_ENTRY'
         STATE_MAP_ENTRY(ST_Start)
         ^
C:\Users\xprk569\StateMachine\StateMachine.h:40:40: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?)
     { reinterpret_cast<StateFunc>(entry) },
                                        ^
C:\Users\xprk569\StateMachine\Motor.h:32:9: note: in expansion of macro 'STATE_MAP_ENTRY'
         STATE_MAP_ENTRY(ST_ChangeSpeed)
         ^
C:\Users\xprk569\StateMachine\StateMachine.h:43:39: error: invalid cast from type 'int' to type 'StateFunc {aka void (StateMachine::*)(EventData*)}'
     { reinterpret_cast<StateFunc>(NULL) }\
                                       ^
C:\Users\xprk569\StateMachine\Motor.h:33:5: note: in expansion of macro 'END_STATE_MAP'
     END_STATE_MAP
     ^
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Can some please explain why is the macro written that way in Motor.h, 
why is it declared like that in StateMachine.h  and
why is the error being thrown ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: "what are BEGIN_STATE_MAP and END_STATE_MAP" - "are the Macros defined in the below header file." I guess you've answered yourself.

Comment: Avoid macros (Do not copy the ancient MFC)

Comment: Yeah, That's correct . They are macros, but cant they be written as functions for making the code understandable. My Question was why are they set as labels in Motor.h, Will edit the question :)

Comment: cannot replicate as I don't have a copy of EventData.h

Comment: @Richard : adding EventData.h .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this code depends on some nonstandard compiler extensions/errors.

To get it to compile (no idea if it will actually work) you need to replace the function names with full qualified member function pointers:

e.g.

```
BEGIN_STATE_MAP
    STATE_MAP_ENTRY(&Motor::ST_Idle)
    STATE_MAP_ENTRY(&Motor::ST_Stop)
    STATE_MAP_ENTRY(&Motor::ST_Start)
    STATE_MAP_ENTRY(&Motor::ST_ChangeSpeed)
END_STATE_MAP
```

After that, you need to figure out a way to overcome the non-conforming cast:

```
/tmp/gcc-explorer-compiler116314-75-1uiyu0/example.cpp: In member function 'virtual const StateStruct* Motor::GetStateMap()':
44 : error: invalid cast from type 'long int' to type 'StateFunc {aka void (StateMachine::*)(EventData*)}'
{ reinterpret_cast<StateFunc>(NULL) }\
^
83 : note: in expansion of macro 'END_STATE_MAP'
```

This cast is completely illegal. If I were you I would throw the code in the trash and rewrite - or use a proven state machine framework like boost meta state machine or boost statechart.

Comment: Why is STATE_MAP_ENTRY(..) between BEGIN_STATE_MAP and END_STATE_MAP, i understand it is macro, but why is it defind that way?

Comment: @user2256825 I am going to guess that it was written years ago under visual studio 5 or 6? Back in those days c++ was a very under-developed language and implementors had to resort to evil tricks.

Answer (score 0):

So you're quickly learning why Macros are no-nos in readable C++. If you get an error, you must expand the macro out to identify where the error is, also you cannot debug into them in most IDEs.

Anyway that said lets get to the expanding, their all the same error so we'll just look at the first one:

> C:\Users\xprk569\StateMachine\Motor.h:29:9: note: in expansion of macro `STATE_MAP_ENTRY`
>   `STATE_MAP_ENTRY(ST_Idle)`
>   C:\Users\xprk569\StateMachine\StateMachine.h:40:40: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the `&` ?)
>   `{ reinterpret_cast<StateFunc>(entry) },`

So this is complaining about line 29: `STATE_MAP_ENTRY(ST_Idle)` So lets expand that:

```
{ reinterpret_cast<StateFunc>(entry) },
```

Obviously this is bad syntax all together outside the scoping of `BEGIN_STATE_MAP` and `END_STATE_MAP`, so in debugging many Macros you'd also have to look at the scoping macros... sometimes they may not be clearly named or delineated unfortunately, but let's finish defining the line we got the error on first. What is this `StateFunc` we're trying to cast to?

```
typedef void (StateMachine::*StateFunc)(EventData *);
```

It's a pointer to a member function which returns a `void` and accepts an `EventData *`. And alarm bells should be going off. You cannot cast to that! `ST_Idle` is of the format: **`void (StateMachine::*)()` so you cannot cast to `void (StateMachine::*StateFunc)(EventData *)`**. This is the same problem for all your functions passed into the macros none of them return a `void` and take an `EventData*`, so even if you fix the syntax, these `reinterpret_cast`s will always return a pointer to a method which is invalid to call, meaning this entire block of Macros is pointless at best and toxic at worst. In the current state you may just as well use none of these Macros or if you need to define the method just do:

```
BEGIN_STATE_MAP
END_STATE_MAP
```

But if you were going to change your method declarations to something more like:

```
void ST_Idle(EventData*);
```

Then you'd need to use this syntax:

```
STATE_MAP_ENTRY(&Motor::ST_Idle)
```

If you're not down with the method pointers they are quite complex. I've typed up a quick example here: http://ideone.com/nL0HnQ Feel free to comment with questions.

**EDIT:**

To expand the Macros here we'll get:

```
public: // BEGIN_STATE_MAP 
const StateStruct* GetStateMap() { // BEGIN_STATE_MAP 
    static const StateStruct StateMap[] = { // BEGIN_STATE_MAP 
    { reinterpret_cast<StateFunc>(ST_Idle) } // STATE_MAP_ENTRY(ST_Idle)
    { reinterpret_cast<StateFunc>(ST_Stop) } // STATE_MAP_ENTRY(ST_Stop)
    { reinterpret_cast<StateFunc>(ST_Start) } // STATE_MAP_ENTRY(ST_Start)
    { reinterpret_cast<StateFunc>(ST_ChangeSpeed) } // STATE_MAP_ENTRY(ST_ChangeSpeed)
    { reinterpret_cast<StateFunc>(NULL) } // END_STATE_MAP
    }; // END_STATE_MAP
    return &StateMap[0]; } // END_STATE_MAP
```

So this set of macros will:

1. Set the scope to `public`
2. Declare the method `GetStateMap`
3. Declare `StateMap` statically local to `GetStateMap`, it will be an array of `StateStruct`s
4. On the first call of the `GetStateMap` method `StateMap` will be initialized to contain method pointers to `ST_Idle`, `ST_Stop`, `ST_Start`, `ST_ChangeSpeed`, and `NULL` `reinterpret_cast` to `StateFunc`s
5. Define `GetStateMap` to return the `StateMap` array

Comment: Thanks , but I did not understand what this syntax does                              BEGIN_STATE_MAP     STATE_MAP_ENTRY(&Motor::ST_Idle)     STATE_MAP_ENTRY(&Motor::ST_Stop)     STATE_MAP_ENTRY(&Motor::ST_Start)     STATE_MAP_ENTRY(&Motor::ST_ChangeSpeed) END_STATE_MAP.                                                     I understood function pointers but dint user stand what the above 5 lines , what begin and end do, why are the function ptrs inside begin and end , why can't they be outside, just wanted to understand the syntax of above 5 lines

Comment: @user2256825 I've edited to explain what these Macros do by expanding them. Hopefully the fact that you need to ask a question on http://www.stackoverflow.com to understand the Macros will discourage you from using them, cause as has been stated many times over Macros are difficult to read, use, maintain, and explain.